# Add to a array using a formula based on the last entry in an array n number of times

Tags: python

I'm attempting to build an array from a known starting value that appends to itself based on a formula that includes the last number of the list. I'd like to do this a specified number of times. So for example:

```
List starts at 5
The formula I use = last number in a list X 2
The new entry to the list is 10
The next new entry is 20
```

My non-working code is below:

```
mean = 198
standard_deviation = 85

list = [((mean)-(standard_deviation*3))]
list.append(((list[-1])+(standard_deviation*.1)))
print(list)

[-55.930192782739596, -47.4592697321513]
```

I'd like to be able to tell the array to stop after 30 entries.

Comment: The description of your algorithm and the code don't seem to match. Maybe `for _ in range(30): list.append(((list[-1])+(standard_deviation*.1)))` ??

Comment: This is exactly right, that resolved it.

`list = [((mean)-(std*3))]`

`for n in range(60): 
    list.append(((list[-1])+(std*.1)))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = [((mean)-(std*3))] 
for n in range(60):      
    list.append(((list[-1])+(std*.1)))
```